# Launch android emulator from avd makes emulator seriously slow

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I've enable Intel HXAM.

Setting "Emulator performance" to Hardware - GLES 2.0

But if I launch it from avd, emulator's performance is really bad.

And If I launch it from command line with option "-gpu on", everything is correct now, emulator is fast and smooth.

Anyone has any idea about this problem? How could I launch emulator from avd with option "-gpu on"?
Thanks!

Comment: Me too saw the difference while i am running the emulator with command line -gpu on . @stevenyoung

Comment: i think *Hardware - GLES 2.0* is the *-gpu on* option . In the android studio they have mentioned  *Hardware - GLES 2.0*  uses yuor computer graphics card .

Comment: @KoVartthan If Hardware - GLES 2.0 is the -gpu on option. Launcher emulator from avd or from command line with "-gpu on" shoule provide the same performance, but as I see it's not..that makes me confused

Comment: you are  correct @steven young

Answer (score 1):

The reason is here and i referred from this link [Click here](https://www.codementor.io/android/tutorial/6-ways-to-supercharge-the-android-emulator)

**GPU emulation**

GPU emulation (sometimes referred to as GPU acceleration) is where the emulator utilises the host machine’s GPU to accelerate drawing options. This can make the emulator run much faster.

GPU Emulation is turned off by default, so you need to enable it whenever you launch an AVD. Although ‘Use Host GPU’ used to appear in the AVD Manager, this option isn’t currently available in Android Studio, but the good news is you can still enable GPU emulation if you launch an AVD from the command line.

To launch your AVD with GPU emulation enabled, create the AVD you want to use as normal. In this example, I’m going to create an imaginatively-named myemulator AVD.

Open your Mac’s Terminal (or Command Prompt, if you’re a Windows user) and then ‘change directory’ so the Terminal is pointing at Android SDK’s ‘Tools’ folder. My command looks like this:

```
cd /Users/jessicathornsby/Library/Android/sdk/tools
```

Next, launch the emulator you created (myemulator) with the -gpu on flag, for example:

```
./emulator @myemulator -gpu on
```

The AVD will launch with graphics acceleration enabled. Spend some time interacting with the AVD, and you should notice a speed improvement.

Comment: Thanks, understand now